# Access VBA: On Error always going to the line intended for error occurrence

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was getting a `Permission denied` error when trying to export a query. The reason why is because sometimes a user leaves the file open. So I decided to try some error handling and make it so that if the `Permission Denied` error occurs, then it should display a `MsgBox` explaining what to do. If there is no permission denied error, then it should just continue and not display the `MsgBox`. However, it is always displaying the `MsgBox`.

**VBA:**

```
Private Sub Command360_Click()

    Dim myQueryName As String
    Dim myExportFileName As String


        myQueryName = "qry_A" 
        myExportFileName = "J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & Me![Combo353].Value & ".xlsx" 
        If Len(myExportFileName) > 0 Then
            On Error GoTo Err_Msg
            Kill myExportFileName
        End If
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, myQueryName, myExportFileName
        Application.FollowHyperlink myExportFileName


Err_Msg: MsgBox "You must close the spreadsheet in order to export.", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: It makes intuitive sense why the `MsgBox` is *always* appearing, I just don't know how to write the code to only make it appear on error (not much VBA experience here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, but I'm open to hearing any critiquing in order to improve this solution.

```
Err_Msg: If (Err.Number = 70) Then MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ")" & Err.Description & ". You must close the spreadsheet in order to export.", vbOKOnly Else Resume Next
```

All I needed to do was add an `If` statement to the `Err_Msg` line where the condition was based on the exact error I wanted to handle.

Comment: It's also very important to utilize `Exit Sub` when you have handling labels like this. Suppose there is no error in the original code, `MsgBox` still appears every time it runs. If you add `Exit Sub` before the `Err_Msg` label, if errors are not thrown the program exits before it reaches the `Err_Msg` and will not open the `MsgBox`. But as you mention in your answer, calling out an error number in an `IF` statement is the best way to trigger specific responses to specific errors.